# Sort list of list using comparable interface

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

I need to sort list of Class based on it's students rollnumber

I/P - `List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();`

o/p - Sorted list based on rollnumber

```
public class Class implements Comparable<Class>{

    List<Student> students;

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Class o) {

    ...
    }

}
```

I want to implement compareTo method of Class such that it will compare students based on their roll numbers.

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String firstname;
    Integer rollnumber;

    public int compareTo(Student o1) {
        if (this.rollnumber == ((Student) o1).rollnumber)
            return 0;
        else if ((this.rollnumber) > ((Student) o1).rollnumber)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How to implement compareTo method for class 'Class' ?

Comment: You don't have to implement `compareTo()` again. Your `Student` class already defines one and it will be used when you call `Collections.sort()`. And please rename the name of *class*. `Class` is already an inbuilt class in java.

Comment: Sounds like u r not interested in comparing `Class` objects. Then what is the use of implementing `Comparable`? You should better add a public method to call `Collections.sort(students)`

Comment: but the i/p I have is List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();  so is it possible to do something like this Collection.sort(classes) where sorting is based on student's rollnumber.

Comment: `I need to sort list of Class based on it's students rollnumber` I think you should reframe it?

Comment: `List<Class> classes`, now a single element of `classes` is List of `Student` no point of have a sort between these list.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output? Two classes can have the same students right?

Answer (score 0):

1. In a `List` a Item can be in **multiple** times. Therefore the same Object that compares to 0 is an unknown order. Use `Set` instead, only a `Set` prevent duplicate values.
2. If you do not like to have empty values, you should use a `TreeSet`.
3. The compare for the rollnumber shall be a natural order, but a `rollnumber`-order is not intuitive, if i would ask you who is the first Student i expect a answer like `Max Mustermann` instead of `23948234`. Sure this is a *intuitive* argument and opinion-based but its like the decision for the natural sort of `String`, its common practice.
4. `TreeSet` can be constructed using a `comparator` implementation as constructor-argument, this shall better fit your needs.
5. If you like DRY use  `Integer.compare`.

So i suggest:

```
private static final Comparator<Student> ROLL_ORDER = new Comparator<Student>(){
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.rollnumber, o2.rollnumber);
    }
}
private final Set<Student> students = new TreeSet<Student>(ROLL_ORDER);
```